# @Output from directive will print in parent but cannot update a value in parent component

Tags: angular, angular-directive

### parent.component.html

```
  <div draggable (dragging)="copyDragging($event)">{{copyBoxDragging}}</div>
```

### parent.component.ts

```
copyDragging(event) {
    console.log('copyDragging :', event); // good
    this.copyBoxDragging = event; // not reflected in html
}
```

### draggable.directive

```
@Output() dragging = new EventEmitter();
mousedrag$.subscribe(() => {
    if (!this._dragging) {
        this.dragging.emit(true);
        this._dragging = true;
    }
});
```

## The Problem

See the `console.log` in **parent.component.ts** ? It is alway correctly prints the expected value. but assigning to a value in parent component (next line) does not reflect in parent html

is there something preventing me from assigning the emitted value in the parent component?

Comment: How do you expect `copyBoxDragging` to be reflected in the parent view? Can we see the relevant HTML code?

Comment: definitely need the relevant html

Comment: @Omar the relevant html is where you're displaying the element... i've been developing angular since v1 beta thanks. good luck to you

Comment: why would that be relevant. its just a `<p>some text</p>`

Comment: because change detection is clearly broken somewhere or you're doing something non typical with your bindings if change detection isn't running on an output event.  Like I said good luck.

Comment: @Omar - You say that assigning `copyBoxDragging` does not reflect in the parent HTML, but that value is not used anywhere in the template, according to the code/markup shown in the question.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using some unincluded code that is running the drag functions outside of ng zone for performance gains and you didn't realize that this would break change detection. the purpose of running outside of ng zone is to turn off change detection, that's where the gains come from.  the fix here is to wrap your event emission in something like `this.ngZone.run(() => this.dragging.emit(true))` rather than forcing consumers of the directive to manually trigger change detection .. components that break change detection aren't very useful as they cause bugs like this

Comment: maybe you can replace directive to cdkDrag component if it possible https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api

Comment: @bryan60 that did the trick

Comment: guess i do know how it all works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to force change detection

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

copyDragging(event) {
    console.log('copyDragging :', event); // good
    this.copyBoxDragging = event; // not reflected in html

    this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: not the problem. output events always trigger change detection

Comment: this solution works... makes me think that maybe change detection doesnt work while keydown or dragging.

Comment: @Omar change detection works fine while keydown or dragging... if you need to force CD in an output event, there is something else wrong in your app that's going to cause issues